# Can't produce a result without hardcoding cookies within the headers of the following script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the zestimate for this address, `1205 Clover St, Accokeek, MD 20607` from this [webpage](https://www.zillow.com/how-much-is-my-home-worth/) using requests module. When I use that address in the inputbox of that webpage, I get this zpid `37374749` number, which, when I use within params and issue a post request, I can get the zestimate.

The problem is the script works only when I hardcode cookies from dev tools within the headers of the requests; otherwise, it fails miserably and throws a JSONDecodeError.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/graphql/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://www.zillow.com/how-much-is-my-home-worth/',
    'cookie': '_px3=00d7bf4fc2e331a793b7ebf9f9e8059013b86b39ead67dfc15fd89fe4e1b459c:GrviXjUIrsA7lYSeSBB8Y8yQedr9ng0ByK7xkaB6CLDFCGYjxBL2r8dPy6MwnUk0Eqv75g0t1fcIa4c8ksIHoA==:1000:1qeUILwk/42tR6FaZ0ybaI63rAWDBAc7fsAeLcH02MyzXKEEoT0SDnk/zMCLA3Zj1BpBmuqO/4RQDntxiOgtsCGPF1VuxfpmXAeMPcxegynJ/PGXWYE3OLIa9vJ9XkVkGaSoH9knD3Ls7nHyuP/0DhapZbThlzDLoQ//Vflzi0eGv12lCSX/2msW+rCeFgO0RhsBMNSN93EUhmuMBXcBMg==;'

}
params = {"operationName":"HowMuchIsMyHomeWorthReviewQuery","variables":{"zpid":37374749},"query":"query HowMuchIsMyHomeWorthReviewQuery($zpid: ID!) {\n  property(zpid: $zpid) {\n    streetAddress\n    city\n    state\n    zipcode\n    bedrooms\n    bathrooms\n    livingArea\n    zestimate\n    homeStatus\n    photos(size: XL) {\n      url\n      __typename\n    }\n    ...OmpHomeWorthUpsell_property\n    isConfirmedClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\n    isVerifiedClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\n    ...UARequiredPropertyDimensions_property\n    ...ContactAgentForm_property\n    ...HomeInfo_property\n    __typename\n  }\n  viewer {\n    ...ContactAgentForm_viewer\n    __typename\n  }\n  abTests {\n    ...OmpHomeWorthUpsell_abTests\n    ...UARequiredPropertyDimensions_abTests\n    ...ContactAgentForm_abTests\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment OmpHomeWorthUpsell_property on Property {\n  zpid\n  onsiteMessage(placementNames: [\"HMIMHWTopSlot\"]) {\n    ...onsiteMessage_fragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment onsiteMessage_fragment on OnsiteMessageResultType {\n  eventId\n  decisionContext\n  messages {\n    skipDisplayReason\n    shouldDisplay\n    isGlobalHoldout\n    isPlacementHoldout\n    placementName\n    testPhase\n    bucket\n    placementId\n    passThrottle\n    lastModified\n    eventId\n    decisionContext\n    selectedTreatment {\n      id\n      name\n      component\n      status\n      renderingProps\n      lastModified\n      __typename\n    }\n    qualifiedTreatments {\n      id\n      name\n      status\n      lastModified\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment OmpHomeWorthUpsell_abTests on ABTests {\n  HMIMHW_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING: abTest(\n    trial: \"HMIMHW_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING\"\n  )\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment UARequiredPropertyDimensions_property on Property {\n  currency\n  featuredListingTypeDimension\n  hasPublicVideo\n  hdpTypeDimension\n  listingTypeDimension\n  price\n  propertyTypeDimension\n  standingOffer {\n    isStandingOfferEligible\n    __typename\n  }\n  zpid\n  isZillowOwned\n  zillowOfferMarket {\n    legacyName\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...ShouldShowVideo_property\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ShouldShowVideo_property on Property {\n  homeStatus\n  isZillowOwned\n  hasPublicVideo\n  primaryPublicVideo {\n    sources {\n      src\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  richMediaVideos {\n    mp4Url\n    hlsUrl\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment UARequiredPropertyDimensions_abTests on ABTests {\n  ZO_HDP_HOUR_ONE_VIDEO: abTest(trial: \"ZO_HDP_HOUR_ONE_VIDEO\")\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_property on Property {\n  streetAddress\n  state\n  city\n  zipcode\n  zpid\n  homeStatus\n  homeType\n  zestimate\n  homeType\n  isInstantOfferEnabled\n  zillowOfferMarket {\n    name\n    code\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_viewer on Viewer {\n  name\n  email\n  zuid\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_abTests on ABTests {\n  SHOW_PL_LEAD_FORM: abTest(trial: \"SHOW_PL_LEAD_FORM\")\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeInfo_property on Property {\n  streetAddress\n  city\n  state\n  zipcode\n  bedrooms\n  bathrooms\n  livingArea\n  homeStatus\n  homeType\n  contingentListingType\n  photos(size: XL) {\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n  listing_sub_type {\n    is_newHome\n    is_FSBO\n    is_bankOwned\n    is_foreclosure\n    is_forAuction\n    is_comingSoon\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.post(url,json=params)
    pprint(res.json()['data']['property']['zestimate'])
```

> How can I find success without hardcoding cookies within the headers?

Comment: You aren't using any cookies in your code example. Cookies are stored in the header named `Cookie`. The header `User-Agent` and `referer` are other typical headers. Setting those headers is prefectly normal when you do scraping. Why is it a problem to set them manually?

Comment: User-agent and referer headers are static, but cookies are meant to change. To run the script successfully, I have to change the cookies frequently, which is what I'm trying to avoid by not hard-coding cookies. I hope it clarifies your question.

Comment: As I said, you aren't adding cookies in your code example. And your code prints `299999` when I run it.

Comment: I've included cookies in the headers.

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to set the cookies in the first place, since the script also delivers a result without them?

Comment: That is great. Although adding cookie makes it much easier to help you, that wasn't my main take away. As @HedgeHog is saying, your code works without the cookies. So there might be something else going on in your code if it is failing. I spammed the endpoint using your original code, and it happily responds with the data.

Comment: I don't understand why the script behaves differently now. I've been trying for several hours to scrape the value without providing cookies, but each time I get a jsondecodeerror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `zpid` dynamically, you have to first submit a request where you put the address. Then use this `zpid` in second request:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.zillowstatic.com/autocomplete/v3/suggestions/"
graphql_url = "https://www.zillow.com/graphql/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://www.zillow.com/how-much-is-my-home-worth/",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    params = {
        "q": "1205 Clover St, Accokeek, MD 20607",
        "resultTypes": "allAddress",
        "resultCount": "5",
    }

    data = s.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    zpid = data["results"][0]["metaData"]["zpid"]

    payload = {
        "operationName": "HowMuchIsMyHomeWorthReviewQuery",
        "query": 'query HowMuchIsMyHomeWorthReviewQuery($zpid: ID!) {\n  property(zpid: $zpid) {\n    streetAddress\n    city\n    state\n    zipcode\n    bedrooms\n    bathrooms\n    livingArea\n    zestimate\n    homeStatus\n    photos(size: XL) {\n      url\n      __typename\n    }\n    ...OmpHomeWorthUpsell_property\n    isConfirmedClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\n    isVerifiedClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\n    ...UARequiredPropertyDimensions_property\n    ...ContactAgentForm_property\n    ...HomeInfo_property\n    __typename\n  }\n  viewer {\n    ...ContactAgentForm_viewer\n    __typename\n  }\n  abTests {\n    ...OmpHomeWorthUpsell_abTests\n    ...UARequiredPropertyDimensions_abTests\n    ...ContactAgentForm_abTests\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment OmpHomeWorthUpsell_property on Property {\n  zpid\n  onsiteMessage(placementNames: ["HMIMHWTopSlot"]) {\n    ...onsiteMessage_fragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment onsiteMessage_fragment on OnsiteMessageResultType {\n  eventId\n  decisionContext\n  messages {\n    skipDisplayReason\n    shouldDisplay\n    isGlobalHoldout\n    isPlacementHoldout\n    placementName\n    testPhase\n    bucket\n    placementId\n    passThrottle\n    lastModified\n    eventId\n    decisionContext\n    selectedTreatment {\n      id\n      name\n      component\n      status\n      renderingProps\n      lastModified\n      __typename\n    }\n    qualifiedTreatments {\n      id\n      name\n      status\n      lastModified\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment OmpHomeWorthUpsell_abTests on ABTests {\n  HMIMHW_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING: abTest(\n    trial: "HMIMHW_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING"\n  )\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment UARequiredPropertyDimensions_property on Property {\n  currency\n  featuredListingTypeDimension\n  hasPublicVideo\n  hdpTypeDimension\n  listingTypeDimension\n  price\n  propertyTypeDimension\n  standingOffer {\n    isStandingOfferEligible\n    __typename\n  }\n  zpid\n  isZillowOwned\n  zillowOfferMarket {\n    legacyName\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...ShouldShowVideo_property\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ShouldShowVideo_property on Property {\n  homeStatus\n  isZillowOwned\n  hasPublicVideo\n  primaryPublicVideo {\n    sources {\n      src\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  richMediaVideos {\n    mp4Url\n    hlsUrl\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment UARequiredPropertyDimensions_abTests on ABTests {\n  ZO_HDP_HOUR_ONE_VIDEO: abTest(trial: "ZO_HDP_HOUR_ONE_VIDEO")\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_property on Property {\n  streetAddress\n  state\n  city\n  zipcode\n  zpid\n  homeStatus\n  homeType\n  zestimate\n  homeType\n  isInstantOfferEnabled\n  zillowOfferMarket {\n    name\n    code\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_viewer on Viewer {\n  name\n  email\n  zuid\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ContactAgentForm_abTests on ABTests {\n  SHOW_PL_LEAD_FORM: abTest(trial: "SHOW_PL_LEAD_FORM")\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeInfo_property on Property {\n  streetAddress\n  city\n  state\n  zipcode\n  bedrooms\n  bathrooms\n  livingArea\n  homeStatus\n  homeType\n  contingentListingType\n  photos(size: XL) {\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n  listing_sub_type {\n    is_newHome\n    is_FSBO\n    is_bankOwned\n    is_foreclosure\n    is_forAuction\n    is_comingSoon\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n',
        "variables": {"zpid": zpid},
    }

    data = s.post(graphql_url, json=payload).json()
    print(data["data"]["property"]["zestimate"])
```

Prints:

```
444700
```

Comment: So, I suppose cookies are not necessary to pass to get the result, right? I followed the exact steps to get the zestimate. I didn't include the whole code only to make the post more concise. It's always a pleasure to find you in the loop, @Andrej.

Comment: @SMTH The server sends some cookies (you can `print(s.cookies)` at the end), so probably they are necessary. But `requests.session()` will handle the cookies in this case for you automatically. The key is to find the right `zpid` - this is why the first request is necessary.